# How to customize svg title in React

Tags: reactjs, svg

In svg file have this svg:

```
<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M16.2856 2H19.5522C20.9037 2 22.0001 3.1059 22.0001 4.47018V7.7641C22.0001 9.12735 20.9037 10.2343 19.5522 10.2343H16.2856C14.933 10.2343 13.8367 9.12735 13.8367 7.7641V4.47018C13.8367 3.1059 14.933 2 16.2856 2Z" stroke="#B5B8BB" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M4.44892 2H7.71449C9.06703 2 10.1634 3.1059 10.1634 4.47018V7.7641C10.1634 9.12735 9.06703 10.2343 7.71449 10.2343H4.44892C3.09638 10.2343 2 9.12735 2 7.7641V4.47018C2 3.1059 3.09638 2 4.44892 2Z" stroke="#B5B8BB" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M4.44892 13.7657H7.71449C9.06703 13.7657 10.1634 14.8716 10.1634 16.2369V19.5298C10.1634 20.8941 9.06703 22 7.71449 22H4.44892C3.09638 22 2 20.8941 2 19.5298V16.2369C2 14.8716 3.09638 13.7657 4.44892 13.7657Z" stroke="#B5B8BB" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M16.2856 13.7657H19.5522C20.9037 13.7657 22.0001 14.8716 22.0001 16.2369V19.5298C22.0001 20.8941 20.9037 22 19.5522 22H16.2856C14.933 22 13.8367 20.8941 13.8367 19.5298V16.2369C13.8367 14.8716 14.933 13.7657 16.2856 13.7657Z" stroke="#B5B8BB" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</svg>
```

I am importing it like this:

```
import { ReactComponent as Icon } from 'assets/icons/icon.svg';
```

And use it just like this:

```
<Icon title="icon title"/>
```

Can I somehow customize this title? I mean change color, background ...

Answer (score 1):

You can provide props into the SVG tag itself, you can see all the tags you can use on SVG tag [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute).

So, to change the color on the SVG, you'd pass "fill" to "red". Here's a sandbox example of [it](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-bush-84o4h).

Comment: Yes, this is good, but i asked if i can styling title(a popup that appears on hover). Do you know something about that?

Comment: Yes, you can add <title>hover popup</title> inside the SVG tag. You can check it here.https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-bush-84o4h?file=/src/icon.svg

Comment: Yes, but can I somehow add styles to this title?

Comment: Sorry, completely misread your post and comment. The popup is purely Browser/OS dependent. You'll need to manually make the popup. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Comment: That's it. Thank you!